How to differentiate between static and interactive server rendering in middleware
The application is a .NET 8 Blazor Web App with Static Server Rendering by default, with most page components having @rendermode InteractiveServer
I need middleware to generate unique nonces per request for different purposes, which are than added to HttpContext.Items.

To be used in App.razor (Static Server Rendering)
... or to be used in page components (Interactive Server rendering)

Is there a decisive way to differentiate between static page requests & interactive page requests? My current approach is filtering the request based on the path, but I feel there should be a better way.
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    string nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    if (IsMainInteractiveRequest(context))
    {
        context.Items.Add("MyInteractiveNonce", nonce);
        context.Response.OnStarting(() => OnStartingCallBackInteractiveRequest(context, nonce));
    }
    else if (IsStaticRequest(context))
    {
        context.Items.Add("MyStaticNonce", nonce);
        context.Response.OnStarting(() => OnStartingCallBackStaticRequest(context, nonce));
    }

    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
    await _next(context);
}

private bool IsMainInteractiveRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context?.Request?.Path != null 
        && context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith("/_blazor"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private bool IsStaticRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context?.Request?.Path != null 
        && context.Request.Method == "GET" 
        && !context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest 
        && !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/_"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

Excluding any path starting with "/_" is needed because otherwise blazor specific requests are not filtered out:

/_framework/blazor.web.js
/_blazor/initializers

The example code works in a simple test setup. But if you add javascript files and css you would need to filter those out. I am looking for a robust solution where I don't need to keep actively updating a list of path exclusions.


Is there a decisive way to differentiate between static page requests
& interactive page requests? My current approach is filtering the
request based on the path, but I feel there should be a better way

Well, based on your shared code snippet and description, it seems that you're filtering requests based on the path.
According to my investigation, your given code is correct. It effectively distinguishes between static and interactive server rendering requests in a Blazor application.
In your InvokeAsync method, you first generate a nonce and then check whether the request is for main interactive rendering or static rendering using the IsMainInteractiveRequest and IsStaticRequest methods, respectively.
Based on the result of these checks, you add the nonce to the HttpContext.Items collection and register a callback to be executed before the response starts.
In addition, I would slidely refactor your IsStaticRequest method  as following:
private bool IsStaticRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    return !IsMainInteractiveRequest(context)
            && context.Request.Method == "GET"
            && !context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest;
}

Note: !IsMainInteractiveRequest(context) would checks if the request is not an interactive Blazor request while context.Request.Method == "GET" ensures the request is a GET request, commonly used for static content. So you don't need to check the path again. As you are checking the path and null value within IsMainInteractiveRequest already.

Excluding a path starting with "/_" is needed because otherwise blazor specific requests are not filtered out (/_framework/blazor.web.js &  /_blazor/initializers)

That's true IsMainInteractiveRequest already doing it, so while I am writing !IsMainInteractiveRequest means either of the condition failed. So yeah, you can also refactor this. But you even could keep yours. I just tried to assist you. Your code seems okay.

IsMainInteractiveRequest checks specifically for a path ending with "/_blazor" so I believe what you are saying is not correct.

Okay, I got your point
